# Как лучше реализовать задержку между http-запросами?

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, http, limit

Собственно проблема с лимитом в 3 запроса в секунду в API VK. Я сделал пока что просто задержку `Thread.sleep(350)` в цикле запросов. Но мне кажется, это не очень красивое решение. Больше похоже на костыль: ведь будут случаи, когда запросы шлются асинхронно из разных мест кода и т.д. Попробовал реализовать очередь, но пока получается довольно страшно: много кода, для вроде бы средней по сложности задачи.

Может кто подскажет лучшее решение? Спасибо!

Comment: Во первых, вы не привели не одного примера с кодом, во вторых за вас никто не будет писать решение и в третьих для таких случаев, есть планировщик задач `Scheduler`.

Comment: Во первых код и не нужен. Я не прошу оптимизировать мой код. Я прошу рассказать какие есть практики для подобных задач. Что бы я не придумывал велосипед. 
во вторых, я не прошу мне написать код. Я прошу описать логику того как можно это сделать. 
в третьих можно было просто написать гугли по Scheduler. А не разжигать срач из-за вашей не внимательности при прочтении моего поста.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал сделать отдельный класс, занимающийся запросами, в котором запоминать время последнего запроса.

Получится что-то такое (код для однопоточного доступа, для многопоточного понадобится синхронизация вокруг работы с `waitForNextSend`):

```
class VkRequester
{
    Task waitForNextSend = Task.CompletedTask; // или Task.FromResult(0) для старых версий
    public async Task<Reply> SendRequest()
    {
        Task oldWait = waitForNextSend;
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
        waitForNextSend = tcs.Task;
        await oldWait;
        WaitHelper(tcs);
        return await <тут отправляете ваш асинхронный запрос>;
    }

    async void WaitHelper(TaskCompletionSource<int> tcs)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0 / 3));
        tcs.SetResult(0);
    }
}
```

Все запросы отправляйте не прямо, а через вот этот класс.

Не тестировал, но вроде должно работать.

Comment: Это намного проще, чем установка таймеров. Спасибо за мысль.

Comment: @АлександрЛи: Пожалуйста! Надеюсь, что поможет

Comment: @VladD,  а зачем tcs? Можно же сразу,  например так https://dotnetfiddle.net/PJOgOM

Comment: @Qutrix: Тут спрятана хитрость. А что если во время первого ожидания откуда-то ещё будет сделан такой же вызов? Тогда он будет дожидаться старого `Delay`'а. И выполнится слишком рано. Насколько я понимаю, необходимо подменять задачу ожидания сразу, до первого `await`'а.

Comment: @Qutrix: Возможно, более изящным было бы решение с `ContinueWith`.

Comment: @VladD, _А что если во время первого ожидания откуда-то ещё будет сделан такой же вызов?_ то продолжение второго вызова подпишется на еще ждущий Delay и после него будут выполнены сразу два продолжения? я правильно понимаю проблему?

Comment: @Qutrix: Именно так. То есть будут отправлены практически одновременно два запроса.

Comment: @VladD, тогда придумал вот так https://dotnetfiddle.net/pZUfuu
можно как-то проще?

Comment: @Qutrix: Двойной таск? Красивый метод отложить создание паузы. А нельзя с одинарным? Когда вычисляется лямбда в `ContinueWith`?

Comment: @VladD, вот не знаю как иначе через `ContinueWith`, как не с двойными тасками. А у Вас есть идеи? И как Вы хотели через `ContinueWith`?

Comment: @Qutrix: Ох, я почему-то думал, что у `ContinueWith` есть unwrap-вариант, как у `Task.Run`, который сам делает внешний `await`. Оказалось, что нету. Тогда наверное проще не выйдет, да.

Comment: @VladD, а еще такой вопрос: можно dotnetfiddle.net/pZUfuu изменить так, чтоб задержка в секунду начиналась только тогда, когда закончится "полезный таск" (ответ от вк), а не строго после предыдущей задержки?

Comment: @Qutrix: По идее, да, если запустить мини-таск, состоящий из `await await oldDelay; return await task()`, новый delay пристыковать в хвост мини-таску, и только после этого за-await-ить мини-таск.

Comment: @VladD, извините, не очень понял мысль

Comment: @Qutrix: Ну, ваш код сейчас подцепляет новый delay к старому. А в новом варианте нужно подцепить его к точке получения результата от vk. Для этого получение результата оформляем в отдельный таск, а чтобы он не стартовал раньше времени, добавляем в этот таск ожидание старого delay.